# Application Menu Item

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a photo-editor app in blackberry. For this I need to open the app through an application menuitem in bb albums; I tried this but it does not get invoked.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. You failed to add menu item?
If this is the case you can check out this:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Create_a_menu_item_508119_11.jsp

You can also find many examples in the sample apps which come from RIM. In eclipse you can easily import the samples from file->import->import blackberry samples.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried of something like this:
ApplicationMenuItemRepository

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_a_menu_item_602617_11.jsp
Not sure whether it works for your case or not